# Switch & Case multiple selections

Tags: php, switch-statement

I got an issue with switch.
Right now from my understanding it works like this:

```
if ( sizeof( $a ) !== sizeof( $types ) ) {
    $type = $a[ 0 ];
    switch ( $type ) {
        case 'Red' :
            $type = 'winered';
            break;
        case 'blue' :
            $type = 'royalblue';
            break;
        case 'yellow' :
            case 'lime' :
            break;
        case 'beige' :
            $type = 'bright';
            break;
        default :
            $type = get_option( 'my_option' );
            break;
    }
} else {
    $type = get_option( 'my_option' );
}
```

So far so good. Whatever I select, it shows the case.
My issue is, it does it only one by one, I am able to select multiple cases like

```
case Red: case Blue:          
$type = 'winered';
break;
```

But this won't work for me. In my scenario it is a checkbox I got case "Red" AND case "Blue" selected and want to display both "results": "winered" AND "royalblue". Right now it falls back to royalblue.

Any suggestions?
Thank you!

Comment: you miss understand about `switch case` ! It can work for only one by one ..

Comment: How do you mean you want to output BOTH results? Both printed to the screen separately or together in 1 string?

Comment: Question isn't really phrased very well.. you might be able to achieve what you want with fall throughs, can't be sure until you clarify what you want though.

Comment: You will need to loop the switch, the switch checks one result.

Comment: Yeah It see, I thought it would be possible to have multiple results instead of one by one.  I have a list and I want to sort it based on the checkboxes. If I select red, it shows all winered, if I select blue, it shows all royalblue. But I want to select red AND blue and it should show me winered AND royalblue.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think it is possible with a switch case to select multiple outcomes. I'd rather use an if statement something like:

```
if($type = 'red' || $type = 'blue'){
  $type = 'winered';
  $type =  $type.'royalblue';
}
```

Comment: `+` is the arithmetic addition (and it works only for numbers). Use the correct [string concatenation operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.useful-funcs) (`.`).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really make sense why it would fall back to `'royalblue'` other than:

1. `'Red' != 'red'`, so it never really goes into the first `case`
2. Maybe this is how you have the types stored in `$a`, so that `$a[0]` is in fact `'blue'`, I would check that.

In any case, if you were interested in combination of different conditions, I would think that 'regular' if-then-else is the way to go. Case is generally faster, but offers itself for 'simpler' conditionals.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I thought about if-then-else but this was a bit too complicate for me, switch seemed to be easier but it really show only one selection. I have a list and I want to sort it based on the checkboxes. If I select red, it shows all winered, if I select blue, it shows all royalblue. But I want to select red AND blue and it should show me winered AND royalblue.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incomplete. However, I think the key is here:

```
$type = $a[ 0 ];
switch ( $type ) {
```

You only check the first value of `$a`. You can check all its values using a simple `foreach`:

```
// Put the selected values here; will join them at the end to get a string
$selected = array();

if (count($a) != count($types)) {
    foreach ($a as $type) {
        switch ($type) {
        case 'Red':
            $selected[] = 'winered';
            break;
        case 'blue':
            $selected[] = 'royalblue';
            break;
        case 'yellow':
        case 'lime':
            // nothing here?!
            break;
        case 'beige':
            $selected[] = 'bright';
            break;
        default:
            $selected[] = get_option('my_option');
            break;
        }
    }
} else {
    $selected[] = get_option('my_option');
}

// Join the selected type with spaces
$type = implode(' ', $selected);
```

Comment: Your example shows me both actions, which is great so far, however, instead of having each entry their own action, entries are now shown with both action regardless of their base. 

So entry `red` becomes action `winered` AND `royalblue` instead of only `winered`. 
Entry `blue` gets action `winered` AND `royalblue` instead of only `royalblue`. 
The solution I’m trying to figure out is to give `red` action `winered` AND `blue` action `royalblue`. 
My OT’s code shows only one at a time since it makes a break. I am sorry for no matter explanation.